# Executing cost distance in memory

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error-999999, in-memory, error-010067

Trying to run cost distance tool in ArcMap, but I keep getting the following results:

```
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
("esriDataSourcesRaster.InMemoryRasterHelper") Failed because of out of memory
ERROR 010029: Unable to create the raster in_memory\CDrast. Cost Distance mapping Failed
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (Cost Distance).
```

Initial thoughts were memory constraints, but I've ran it on several computers with high ram (~ 16 to 40 GB) and still got the same error codes. The inputs are 4 bit Int TIFFs (~1.8 GiB), which were compressed to 2 bit TIFFs (~930 MiB) again still same error codes. I can successfully save it to a path, but when it comes to `in_memory` the tool does not work.

Comment: 32-bit applications cannot use that much RAM -- The effective limit is closer to 800Mb. In the future please specify the size of the raster(s).

Comment: The 4 bit rasters are ~1.8 GiB and 2 bit rasters are ~ 930 MiB. Also, by effective size limit are you referring to the size of the input rasters? I can try compressing them further and see if it is successful.

Comment: "Effective size limit" is the sum of all objects placed in the heap (including the Python language itself). Individual objects shoildnt exceed *50Mb*.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain details instead  of placing the in the comments.

Comment: That complicates the issue because the heap will be greater than 1 GiB. I believe running this `in_memory` isn't an option. Do you recommend any other strategies to speed up processing of cost distance tool?

Comment: Modern operating systems cache filesystem blocks, so I question whether there would be any real benefit, but the 64-bit Background Geoprocessing  module has a larger heap space available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much experimentation and help from @Vince, @Curtis Price and other GIS professionals. We believe that the issue is related to how ArcGIS handles RAM usage and large rasters `in_memory` so the best work around is running 64-bit geoprocessing which considerably improved our run-times (32bit run-time ~1.2 hrs and 64bit run-time ~0.8). Also, other factor was use of SSDs improved the processing speed as well. The original reason for running CD in_memory was to improve workflow speed which has been achieved, but it still doesn't entirely explain why does `in_memory` fails despite under aforementioned circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If running in ArcMap foreground processing, you have to fit ArcMap, Python and your data into a limited space (3.2 GB). Have you tried running this workflow in background processing, or standalone from a Python script?

Comment: So far we've tried the following methods:

- Tried running CD tool in_memory with 64-bit Background Geoprocessing as suggested by @Vince. The tool runs for 7 minutes or so, but no cost distance raster is produced

- Tried using ArcPro and tried running it in_memory gives us the same result as above

So far we were able to slice a piece of the raster (~1/10th of original size) and it successfully run it in_memory, but slicing the rasters and incorporating them into our workflow is something we'd like to avoid.